# Continuity of polynomials using sequence definition of continuity.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The three step continuity definition states that :

> $f(x_0)$ exists;
>
> $\lim_{x \to x_o} f(x)$ exists; and
>
> $\lim_{x \to x_o} f(x)$ =$f(x_o)$.

can we use this definition to prove that $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\ldots+a_nx^n$ is continuous at every point $x \in \mathbb R$.
If not, then how can we prove it. Please help$\ldots$

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Polynomial_is_Continuous I am using my phone and I can't writ the answer so try searching on Google or follow the link

Comment: @user291957 Thanks for the link.

Comment: I think you got your proof from the link ????

Comment: @user291957 yes,I got the proof,thanks.

Comment: mention not. I am adding this link to the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use it but you should also apply limit laws since it is summation of individual functions i.e., $x , x^2....$ and so on.

here is the link for the proof https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Polynomial_is_Continuous

Comment: The thing is I don't know how to prove it?Please help. I already upvoted for you.