# continuity and limit of a function.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Below is the question:

> To what degree would the sequence definition of continuity need to be modified in order to be suitable as a definition for the limit of a function?
>
> In other words,if $f$ is a function and if $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is any sequence of domain points such that $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $x_o$,then lim$_{x\to x_o}$$f(x)=L$ iff
> $\ldots$ ?

{HERE Sequence definition of continuity is

> $f(x_0)$ exists;
>
> $\lim_{x \to x_o} f(x)$ exists; and
>
> $\lim_{x \to x_o} f(x)$ =$f(x_o)$.

}

I cannot understand what should be iff case?Please help...

Comment: Well, for sure one needs to add that $\;f(x_0)\;$ exists and also that $\;L=f(x_0)\;$

Comment: You've previously referred to a "sequence definition of continuity" in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934725/continuity-of-polynomials-using-sequence-definition-of-continuity and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934908/definition-of-continuity, but in what way does that definition use sequences?

Comment: There is a definition of continuity using sequences (as explained in an answer, below) but it is not what you stated as the "sequence definition" above--or am I missing something there?

Comment: @DavidK I'm using the book -'Exploratory examples for real analysis' where it is stated to be the sequence definition of continuity.What I think it is due to the fact that when a function is defined at $x=x_o$,i.e.,the value of real no. $f(x_o)$ exists,and as $x$ approaches $x_o$,the graph of $f$ approaches $f(x_o)$,i.e $lim_{x \to x_o}$$f(x)$ exist and is equal to $f(x_o)$

Comment: I don't have a copy of the book, so I don't know what it actually says about this or what I'm missing here. Perhaps a more complete quote (including some of the text just before the definition) would help to clear this up.

Answer (score 1):

I think given $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, as long as the set 
$$A: = \{x\in \mathbb{R} : f(x) \text{ is discontinuous }\}$$
contains no Cauchy sequences, we will be able to say that 
$$\lim_{x_n\rightarrow x} f(x_n) = L$$
for some real number $L$.

**Edit:** And you can only have removable discontinuity. I forgot to mention this.

Containing no Cauchy sequence prevents the case where $x_n\rightarrow x$ and $f$ is discontinuous at each $x_n$, in this case you have no way of controlling the value of $f(x_n)$.

When you take the limit 
$$\lim_{x_n\rightarrow x} f(x_n),$$
if $f$ is continuous at $x$, we are done; else if $f$ is not continuous at $x$, since the function only has removable discontinuity, then 
$$\lim_{x_n\rightarrow x} f(x_n) = L\neq f(x).$$

Answer (score 0):

If it concerns a continuous function $f$ then ...? in your question must be filled in with: $L=f(x_0)$

---

- Function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous at $x\in X$ iff $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(x_n)=f(x)$ is true for every sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ that converges to $x$.
- Function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous iff it is continuous at every $x\in X$.

Comment: but the firstline of question states that "To what degree would the sequence definition of continuity need to be modified in order to be suitable as a definition for the limit of a function ?" How is your answer related to it..

Comment: What in fact **is** 'the limit of a function'??? Can you give me a definition of the limit of a function $f$?

Comment: Let $f(x)$ be defined on an open interval about $x_o$ ,except possibly at $x_o$ itself.We say that $f(x)$ approaches the limit L as $x$ approaches $x_o$,and write lim$_{x \to x_o} f(x)=L$ , if for every no. $\epsilon \gt 0$,there exists a corresponding no. $\delta \gt 0$ such that for all $x$ ,       0<|$x-x_o$|<$\delta $ $\implies $ $|f(x)-L$|<$\epsilon $

Comment: Here you are talking about the limit of $f$ **at** $x_0$. If $f$ is not defined at $x_0$ then nothing can be said about continuity. If $f$ is also defined at $x_0$ then you can say that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ iff $f(x_0)=L$.

Comment: 'The limit of function $f$' is not a properly defined concept. This in contrast to 'the limit of function $f$ at $x$' which is properly defined under suitable conditions.